# SQL to ONLY Extract Single Word or Number after a Keyword in String

Tags: sql, replace, substring

```
SELECT 
 NOTE_ID    
,NOTE_DATE  
,NOTE_TEXT  
FROM NOTE.dbo.NOTE_TABLE
```

From the above simple query, I get:

| NOTE_ID | NOTE_DATE | NOTE_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 54876 | 2020-10-12 | Purpose: Traveling Salesman Visit Customer Name: John Doe Date Account |
|  |  | Opened: 6/8/19 Customer Address: 428 S. Palm Tree Lane Lokey AZ 85546 Primary |
|  |  | Account Rep: Hank Stank Customer Account #: 1234567 Customer Preferred |
|  |  | Contact Time: Evenings Customer Owns/Rents: Owns Customer Employed: Yes |
|  |  | Customer Military Discount: No Customer Returns: No |

I want to be able to extract only the Customer Account # "1234567" (or if it's null/"UNKNOWN" - whatever comes after Customer Account # and before Customer Preferred Contact Time. I have tried various Substring functions to get to the Customer Account #, but unable to delete everything after it. Any advice would be appreciated.

Note that the NOTE_TEXT field is all on one row. Not sure why it shows it broken up on multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex string parsing (which SQL really is not very good at), I use layers of CROSS APPLY's so I can find one piece a time. It really helps me keep track of each layer and debug each step by step.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Note
Create Table #Note (
    NOTE_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,NOTE_DATE DATE
    ,NOTE_TEXT Varchar(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #Note
Values(54876,'2020-10-12', 'Purpose: Traveling Salesman Visit Customer Name: John Doe Date Account Opened: 6/8/19 Customer Address: 428 S. Palm Tree Lane Lokey AZ 85546 Primary Account Rep: Hank Stank Customer Account #: 1234567 Customer Preferred Contact Time: Evenings Customer Owns/Rents: Owns Customer Employed: Yes Customer Military Discount: No Customer Returns: No')
,(62345,'2020-11-11', 'Customer Account #: 123 blah') /*Value at beginning of text*/
,(67890,'2021-02-28', 'Blah Customer Account #: 456') /*Value at end of text*/
,(99999,'2022-01-01', 'No matching account #') 



DECLARE @SearchPhrase AS Varchar(20) = 'Customer Account #:';

SELECT *
    ,AccountNumberParsedFromNote = SUBSTRING(NOTE_TEXT,B.IDX1,C.IDX2-B.IDX1)
FROM #Note AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IDX1 = NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@SearchPhrase, NOTE_TEXT),0) + LEN(@SearchPhrase) + 1) AS B /*Index of letter after search phrase*/
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IDX2 = CHARINDEX(' ',NOTE_TEXT + ' '/*Trailing space accounts for value at end of string*/,B.IDX1)) AS C /*Index of end of next word after search phrase*/
```

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as accepted so others know your question is answered

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there's probably a better way to do this but it should match the phrase `Customer Account #:`

```
DECLARE @searchPhrase AS CHAR(20) = 'Customer Account #: ';
SELECT IIF(PhraseExists > 0, SUBSTRING(CustomerNumNextPhrase, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', CustomerNumNextPhrase)), 'UNKNOWN') AS Account
FROM (SELECT CHARINDEX(@searchPhrase, NotesData) AS PhraseExists,
             REPLACE(NotesData, SUBSTRING(NotesData, 0, CHARINDEX(@searchPhrase, NotesData) + 20), '') AS CustomerNumNextPhrase
      FROM test.dbo.Notes) A;
```

The inner query reports a 0 if it cannot find the phrase `Customer Account #:`  and the outer query reports `UNKNOWN` in that case. If the inner query reports anything other than 0, it returns a substring of the main string where it cuts off everything before `Customer Account #:` as well as the `Customer Account #:` phrase itself. Then the outer query gets a substring of the next keyword up until the next space.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will give this a test and let you know how it turns out.